# View previous page data without load in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Routes :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider

            .when("/home/:page", {templateUrl: "templates/home.html", controller: "HomeController"})

            .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
        }]);

Controller :


     App.controller('HomeController', function ( $scope, $location, $http,defaultVal,$routeParams ,basic,State) {
    $scope.allList = State.formData;
    start = $routeParams.page == undefined ? 1 : $routeParams.page;
    var trip_data = {
        start:(Number(start)-1) * (Number(defaultVal.perPage)),
        perpage:defaultVal.perPage
    }
    basic.hitAPI(defaultVal.sitePath+"search",{reqObject:JSON.stringify(trip_data)}).success(function(response){
        if(response.type == "success"){
            p = Number(start)- Number(1) < 0 ? false : Number(start)-Number(1);
            result = Math.ceil(response.total / defaultVal.perPage);
            n = Number(start) + Number(1) > result ? false : Number(start) + Number(1);
            response.page = {
                next : n,
                prev: p
            };
            $scope.allList = response;
            State.formData = $scope.allList;
        } else if(response.type == "error"){
            basic.messages.showErrorMessage(response.message);
        }else{
            basic.messages.generalError();
        }
    });
});
```

Template :

```
<div class="trips" >
    <div class="tripBox" ng-repeat="Home in allList.data" 
         ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft('/home/{{allList.page.next}}')"
         ng-swipe-right="swipeRight('/home/{{allList.page.prev}}')">
        <a ng-href="#/trip/{{Home.id}}">
        <h3>{{ Home.FromAddress }}  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> {{ Home.ToAddress }}</h3>
        <div class="poolPrice">${{ Home.charges }}</div>
        <p><span>Posted By :</span> {{ Home.UserName }}, 24 yrs, {{ Home.UserGender | capitalize }}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that after paginate when I go back then it again send request to server for data. I want when I go back then it show previous data without send request to server.

Comment: looks like you provided wrong controller in question. How your HomeController looks like?

Comment: Ya.. you are write. but now i correct it.. please give a solution now, thnks

Comment: You can keep a flag inside your `service`, something like `isContentLoaded = false`, set it to `true` when you first time load your controller (change it inside your controller). When you change your route again, you can check that variables and not perform sending request to server when that `isContentLoaded` is `true`. But I suggest you should use [route resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) inside your routing. Remember that `controller` will be destroyed when you change route but `service` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you go back some view (which were before current)  is have to be rendered (no mater what page we are talking about home or rtip)  if controller of this page calling service unconditionally then it of course will be requested again (i thing angular make browser to not cache its pages).  Looks like you use some state storage ($scope.allList = State.formData;) isn't you?  Then you can store data needed for page and in controller check its existance first and if it not then call API, but in this case your page may become inactual with time.

Comment: $scope.allList = State.formData; store the current data. but after pagination its replace the last value.

Comment: you may store data in dufferen varaibles  State.homeData,  State.TripData   and so on,  but in this case there will be another problem, when open Home page it will display always same data, so you will need to store for different homes for ex: State.home1  State home555  etc. -  which is not good i think.

anyway  if you don want to not request list data  on return to list, just do not store items data in list's storage.

also, it is not an answer,  but  look at  https://www.ng-book.com/p/Caching/